# number of servers running app in cluster

Tags: web-services, weblogic, jmx, cluster-computing

I have a web service app running in a cluster on WebLogic 10.3.  Can anyone tell me if there is a way to programmatically determine  the number of servers in the cluster that currently have the app up and running?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Respectfully,
Kal

Answer (score 1):

I think your best best is to use WLST scripting

Connect to each of the running Servers in the cluster and see within the list of deployed (or running) apps if yours is present

There are commands for all this - look at the list below

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/config_scripting/reference.html#1024213